# BGL: call to strong_components fails to compile when random_spanning_tree.hpp is included

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

This is a weird one, I was hoping to use `boost::random_spanning_tree` in an existing function which also calls `boost::strong_components` but simply including `boost/graph/random_spanning_tree.hpp` without otherwise modifying the code causes gcc to produce a compilation error.

The function looks something like this:

```
#include "boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp"
#include "boost/graph/strong_components.hpp"                                    
//#include "boost/graph/random_spanning_tree.hpp" // can't include this!

void foo() {
  boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> g;

  // TODO: add some vertices

  std::vector<unsigned> component(boost::num_vertices(g));
  unsigned num = boost::strong_components(g, &component[0]);
}
```

and gcc complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘get(unsigned int*&, boost::graph_traits<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> >::vertex_descriptor&)’
           if (get(comp, w) == (std::numeric_limits<comp_type>::max)())
```

Is the code itself flawed or is this an issue with Boost?

EDIT:

I must apologize, I have made a slight mistake in my minimal example, the code above only fails to compile on my system (Linus, g++ 8.2.1, Boost 1.67) if `boost/graph/random_spanning_tree.hpp` is included *before* `boost/graph/strong_components.hpp`. Using wandbox, I have found no combination of compiler / Boost version for which this does not happen.

I would file a ticket for this but Boost makes this needlessly difficult (I don't have `TICKET_CREATE` rights for Boost's Trac but how to obtain those is not specified anywhere).

Comment: Which Boost version is this? Which gcc version is this? I'd like to reproduce the exact error you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem here: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1c8a6973c8ea6f2)**

> Also try
>
> - https://wandbox.org/permlink/jDIYB9oCjAP2wxHo wandbox which lets you switch compiler versions, flags and every possible boost version

Which leads me to believe it's a problem with the rest of your code/compiler config.

Are you on windows? I see `max` which is a MACRO in `windows.h`. Be sure to not include that (also check `stdafx.h` if you use it)

## UPDATE

After your edit I was able to repro the error. That's a bug in boost, and I've created a ticket for it at [the bug tracker](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/116)

Comment: "Are you on windows?" Well, the OP did say they used gcc. Even then, I'm pretty sure that `max` is a function-style macro in `windows.h`, meaning that `(std::numeric_limits<comp_type>::max)` would not trigger the macro (probably why it was wrapped in parens)

Comment: If you have MSVC, are you using Boost 1.60? Is [this](http://rextester.com/MJZCP80995) the same error? That also appears when **not** including `random_spanning_tree.hpp`. If so, try to upgrade the compiler and/or boost.

Comment: I'm an Linux (Arch) using Boost 1.67 and gcc 8.2.1. I just realized that I have made a mistake when verifying my MCVW and the code I have posted actually does compile on my system, just not when the code within the function body is located somewhere in my original source code file (and the problematic header is included). This might be a problem with my build system, I will try to pinpoint what is actually causing this.

Comment: In response to your updated question I have created [a ticket at BGL](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/116): looks like a partial ordering bug due to the fact that `reverse_graph.hpp` defines a `get` overload directly inside the `boost::detail` namespace, which breaks ADL. There's a workaround in the ticket (if you are willing to locally modify the `strong_components.hpp` header)

Comment: So, to be clear: it's not an issue on your end. Boost needs to fix it. You can only work around it for now (I'd simply change the order of includes)

Comment: That's what I've done, I guess I can live with that.